# Update XML element value without modifying the structure in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

My requirement is to update a value of an XML element in Groovy. Below is the code. The code is to update the state to enabled if the name is Super1.

```
def xmlfile = new File("D:/z/Test.xml")
def people = new XmlParser().parse(xmlfile)
people.Plugins.Plugin.findAll { p ->
  if(p.Name.text()=="Super1")
  {
    p.State[0].value="Enabled"
    println(p.State.text())
  }
}
def stringWriter = new StringWriter()
new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter)).print(people)
def newXml = stringWriter.toString()
println("Updated Ec2ConfigService Test xml")
xmlfile.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n"+newXml)
```

XML input:

```
<RootNode>
  <Parent>
    <Test>
        <Name>Super1</Name>
        <State>Disabled</State>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Name>Super2</Name>
        <State>Disabled</State>
    </Test>
</Parent>
```

XML output:

```
<RootNode>
<Parent>
    <Test>
        <Name>
          Super1
        </Name>
        <State>
          Enabled
        </State>
    </Test>
    ........
</Parent>
```

Excepted output:

```
<RootNode>
<Parent>
    <Test>
        <Name>Super1</Name>
        <State>Enabled</State>
    </Test>
    ........
</Parent>
```

Here the code is working correctly but changing the allignment of the elements. How can I update the element without modifying the alignment?

Comment: Appreciate if you can upvote the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as specified below.

- find `Test` nodes where `Name` is matching
- Then replace the value using `replaceBody` for `State`
- by using map (for replace different `Name` with different `State`)

```groovy
//Added additional node for the tests
def inputXml = '''<RootNode>
  <Parent>
    <Test>
        <Name>Super1</Name>
        <State>Disabled</State>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Name>Super2</Name>
        <State>Disabled</State>
    </Test>
    <Test>
        <Name>Super1a</Name>
        <State>Disabled</State>
    </Test>
</Parent>
</RootNode>'''


//Defined map for replacement k, v pair
def changeMap = ['Super1': 'Enabled', 'Super1a': 'Enabled']

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(inputXml)

changeMap.collect { k, v -> def tests = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Name' && it == k}*.parent().State*.replaceBody(v) }

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

You can quickly try the same using online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/J2bSUU)</kbd>

If you are using xml file instead of string, you can use below:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('D:/z/Test.xml'))

def changeMap = ['Super1': 'Enabled', 'Super1a': 'Enabled']

changeMap.collect { k, v -> def tests = xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'Name' && it == k}*.parent().State*.replaceBody(v) }

println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```